# Add list of hours in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using datatable to show the records.Here i have a column which showing hours spent and a row which shows the total hours (Adding all the hours spent using function empPageChange(event)).Here hours are added perfectly but minutes shows `NaN` like `52:Nan`.Can anyone help me to sort out this

**component.ts**

```
empPageChange(event) {
    let list = this.timetables.slice(event.first, event.first + event.rows);
    if (list.length > 0) {
        this.totalHoursSpent = HelperService.addTimes(list, 'HoursSpent');
    } else {
        this.totalHoursSpent = 0;
    }
}
```

**helper.service.ts:**

```
 static addTimes(timeMap, columnName: string) {
    let totalH = 0;
    let totalM = 0;

    // First simply adding all of it together, total hours and total minutes
    for (let x in timeMap) {
        if (x) {
            let timeArray = timeMap[x][columnName].split(':');
            let hour = timeArray[0];
            let minutes = timeArray[1];
            totalH += parseInt(hour, 10);
            totalM += parseInt(minutes, 10);
        }
    }

    // If the minutes exceed 60
    if (totalM >= 60) {
        // Divide minutes by 60 and add result to hours
        totalH += Math.floor(totalM / 60);
        // Add remainder of totalM / 60 to minutes
        totalM = totalM % 60;
    }
    return `${totalH}:${
        totalM.toString().length === 1 ? `0${totalM}` : totalM
        }`;
}
```

Comment: Check your timeArray. See is the second value is actually a number. NaN stands for not a number.

Comment: Besides making sure that your input data is correct, you might also want to use a well-tested date/time library, like perhaps date-fns (https://date-fns.org/)

Comment: for (let x **in** timeMap) or for (let x **of** timeMap) ?

Comment: It is because of wrong input value.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since that you are having that **NaN**, a couple of considerations:

- Are you sure that your **timeArray** is containing just numbers?, maybe you can do a `console,log(timeArray[1])` to validate it. Maybe the **TotalM** variable too.
- Is it possible that your minutes are comming in decimals?, is it possible that if are decimals and your current culture puts "." as decimal separator makes that is not a number.

  `isNaN(Number("10,5")) //true`

  `isNaN(Number("10.5")) //false`

Comment: I have found the issue.It is due to wrong input value.Thanks